# Accepting SAML token from third-party to allow access to our RDweb application

Tags: authentication, adfs

We have an RDweb hosted application, which until now has access control performed by a form and username/password authenticated against active directory.

A third-party wishes to use their own web-portal for access control, then send us a SAML token containing an assertion, and then we will grant access to our application based on this token.

I have managed to build out a C# solution which can accept a SAML token and then impersonate a given active directory user, but this is independent of RDweb.

RDweb seems to only support forms based authentication (which needs a user/pass) or Windows Authentication. Windows Authentication works on the local domain when the browser is setup correctly, but I cannot see that it is going to work on customer's browsers across the Internet.

I feel like I am missing something here - is there a simple solution to accepting SAML and using it to access RDweb?

Comment: "but I cannot see that it is going to work on customer's browsers across the Internet.". Can you please show me where you're going wrong.? I mean some image or some other.

Comment: I don't understand I am afriad - how would an image clarify? Integrated windows authentication isn't support by all browsers and proxies frequently remove the headers in corporate environment. Experience with it says it is not going to work for as many people as we need.

Comment: It looks like RDWeb is served via IIS.  I would hope then that any authentication provider that works with IIS would work with RDWeb.  One such authentication provider is Shibboleth.